# What are best practices for loading data in Backbone Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Most examples I see load an entire collection of data when the app loads.

My first app is pretty simple. I menu region with a list of clickable articles, and an article details region with the full article.  If I have a collection of articles, my data could be pretty big eventually.

If loading everything in a giant collection isnt the way to go, is there a better example someone could point me to that shows me how to lazy load my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes from personal experience with this:

- Loading all data is generally a bottleneck on the DB, not on the client. If you can optimize your DB, then client can handle a few hundred articles easily, possibly more.
- If you want your app to eventually also become an HTML5 mobile app wrapped in Cordova or WebWorks, then none of the bootstrapping would be applicable and you'd need to load all data dynamically.
- On mobile devices (browser or cordova is irrelevant), it matter more that you don't render off-screen elements than that you don't load them in the first place. Of course, you still have less memory to work with, but if you render you entire collection then rendering and scrolling will be the culprit, not memory.
- On desktop browsers, preloading data provides for a much much smoother experience. Even if you only load top 10 articles initially, immediately pre-fetch the rest of the relevant data.
- If your models have a lot of "related" models or data, you could use [Backbone-Relation](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) `fetchRelated` as a dirty hack, but this method is too inefficient for most use cases.
- If you're planning on dynamically loading/unloading article-related data when the article details are displayed, I'd recommend managing that explicitly in your Application object or the view. There are caching apps for Backbone if you'd like to cache the data (and you should). A simple flag on the article model to indicate whether the data was fetched or not would be sufficient for managing the fetching/caching.
- If your data is highly dynamic, then, at least initially to keep things simple, don't cache but fetch the dynamic parts every time.

Hope this helps. If you have more specific concerns, please update your question or post a comment.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't so much a Marionette question as it is a question on what data should be bootstrapped vs what data should not be.

The general rule is:

If you need the data always, no matter what is being shown on the screen, bootstrap it. If you don't need it always, don't bootstrap it.

There are nuances that you can argue within that, of course, but it generally works out pretty well.

As for bootstrapping data w/ Marionette, when it makes sense... the `Application.start` method takes a parameter for this, and passes it along to all initializers.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#starting-an-application

Comment: `start` made me a day! That's the comfortable place to go. Thank you Derick.

Answer (score 0):

I'd [bootstrap](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#bootstrapping_data) a paged collection of articles (meaning the 10 most recent for examples). And as the user scrolls down for example, I'd load the next 10 or whatever number makes sense. There are examples across the web for this technique.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not so worried about the number of elements in the collection, but the size of the data in each of the models in the collection.